# How to convert the report to an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image, reporting-services

I use `Report viewer` to show my reports .

---

Now I want to convert the report to an image . How it possible to convert the RDLC report to an image to draw on it later .

Is there any library or method to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create an instance of your `ReportViewer`:

```
ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();
```

Set up it with proper properties according to the report type you're about to create and passing all parameters it needs, for example:

```
report.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
report.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
report.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

Now you can ask the `ReportViewer` to render the report in the format you prefer, it'll return to you a byte array that you can simply stream to the client or save somewhere:

```
byte[] reportContent = report.ServerReport.Render(reportFormat);
```

`reportFormat` is a `string` with the required format, for example to get a `.TIF` image you have to ask for the `"IMAGE"` format, for a `.PDF` file you have to ask for `"PDF"` (consult MSDN for other supported formats, they depends on the version you're using).

Now you can simply save `reportContent` to a file (or to stream it in the response, adding appropriate headers):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, reportContent);
```