# How to save RDLC report as image file?

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, rdlc, crystal-reports-2010, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am trying to save RDLC report as image file on local drive. I am able to show image in report.
But I don't know how to save as image file. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi check the next link i hope it help you

[How to convert the report to an image?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013295/how-to-convert-the-report-to-an-image